# How forbid deleting files from an USB flash drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, flash

I have an USB flash drive and I would like to give it as a present. My purpose is to insert three files and make them unerasable.

Is it possible?
Should I create a read-only partition in the flash drive?

Comment: ... why do you want that?

Answer (score 2):

While you could set them as "read only", there is no hardware enforced method of preventing file modification or deletion by the operating system or applications like the "write protect" tab on floppy disks. The "read only" attribute would only make the operating system ask if they were "extra sure" they wanted to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done without hardware designed specifically to do so. You would have to have a special drive with two separate memory chips inside. One with EEPROM and the other with fixed unwriteable ROM.